# Swagger-ui: How to configure to serve with MVC core project

Tags: authorization, access-token, identityserver4, swagger-ui

How to configure the swagger-ui to call the web api if the authorized attribute was set on the controller. I have configured but couldn't have it work or am I doing the wrong way.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info
            {
                Title = "Parent Side HTTP API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "The Parent Side Microservcie HTTP API",
                TermsOfService = "Term Of Service"
            });
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
            {

                Type = "oauth2",
                Flow = "implicit",
                AuthorizationUrl = $"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrlExternal")}/connect/authorize",
                TokenUrl = $"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrlExternal")}/connect/token",
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "api1", "Read access to protected resources" }
                }
            });

            options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        //services.AddCustomMvc(Configuration)
        //    .AddCustomAuthentication(Configuration);
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        var identityUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("urls:identity");
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrlExternal");
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = "parent.api.gateway";              
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctx =>
                {
                    int i = 0;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                {
                    int i = 0;
                }
            };
        });

        services.AddMvc(); 
        //    .AddIdentityServerAuthent;

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseSwagger()
           .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Parent API V1");
           }); 

        app.UseAuthentication();  

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

[image]

What it does only show on a new browser of the identity server login page. Once I do a login, it only stay on the same login screen even though its been logged in.

I even use BasicAuthScheme which showing the login popup. The popup also display as authorized but the api listed is still unauthorized. Is it possible to call those Authorized Code to be executed once I authorized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swagger 3.0, The popup doesn't close itself until you click "Close".

And I see you added scope, but you don't seem to apply it to any controllers. You have to call AddSecurityRequirement() after AddSecurityDefinition().

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. At the moment, I pass the token into api itself.